# How do I fully extract this bicycle from the background, including the spokes, etc. using Gimp

Tags: gimp, images, crop

I'd like to pull the bicycle out of the image, but can't seem to make any of the Gimp tutorials work.

[image: Picture]

Comment: In this case, you need to draw the mask by hand, That includes drawing thin lines, the circles etc. It is better to take a new photo on a flat background.

Comment: You can't even **see** all the spokes properly. How do you expect to extract something you can't even see?

Comment: I concur with Rafael. A very lengthy session with the Path tool, or reshoot.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution of the image isn't enough for the job. In addition the image is spoiled by JPG artifacts. More: There are black details against black background - needs guessing. In theory you can draw a clipping mask (a hefty job) with the pen tool or erase the background literally pixel by pixel. The result will be at best poor, more probably inferior due the low resolution.

Your best bet is to take a new photo. Do the photo session targeting to the background removal. Have

- a high resolution camera, preferably RAW capable to stay away from JPGs
- strong and uniform light with no shadows and strong glossy areas!
- featureless, preferably grey background. Single color background is ok if you can keep that color out of the bike with stronger white light on the bike